# To Bottle or Not to Bottle?

Tags: fermentation

I'm using a Mr.Beer Home Brew Kit. First Batch, its been 14 days of fermentation, still cloudy, took a sample taste and it taste like flat beer, should I bottle or wait a few more days to see if it clears up anymore?

Comment: Do you know your original gravity (OG), and whether or not you hit your anticipated final gravity (FG)?

Answer (score 2):

If you believe fermentations is complete (No more bubbles in airlock or correct FG), You have a few options.

1. Continue to wait and let gravity slowly do it's thing.
2. Carefully transfer the beer to the fridge and [Cold Crash](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/what-is-cold-crashing) your beer. Particles including [Chill Haze](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/what-is-chill-haze-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-chill-haze) will fall out of suspension, given time.
3. Feeling impatient, you could bottle the beer now and just be left with a bit more sediment in the bottles.
4. Feeling impatient with pocket change, Go to Homebrew shop and buy some [Fining](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11365/what-are-finings-how-does-finings-work) which is something you add to clear the beer.

I'd recommend option 1 or 2 if your new. You have plenty of time to faff around with finings on other batches.

This Question may be helpful if and when it is answered.
[What Are Finings? How Does Finings Work?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11365/what-are-finings-how-does-finings-work)
[What is Cold Crashing?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/what-is-cold-crashing)
[What is Chill Haze?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/what-is-chill-haze-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-chill-haze)

Comment: As a small note, no bubbles in the airlock is actually not a very good indicator of finished fermentation. FG is the only way you will know for sure.

Comment: I had bucket style fermentation vessels and the lids started out airtight, but soon the air-locks didn't bubble I was worried for a while until I think CraigTube said the lids often leak out the side and some people don't bother with the airlock.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to wait out that first batch eh? I know, been there like most of the guy (and gals) here.

Im with Another Compiler Error in waiting it out. I have found that in most cases, (I've only brewed ales so far) that fermentation is finished within the first 10 days, but the longer I let it sit (so far up to 4 weeks) the better it comes out.

I would say instead of buying finings, I would buy another fermenter and some ingredients and make another batch to keep you busy :)

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that you have reached your FG. If that is the case go ahead and bottle the beer.  After it is carbonated and you put it in the fridge to cool off for a few days it will clear some more.
If you are looking for more clear beer you can try to add some finings to your beer your homebrew shop will help you pick some out.