# What are finings? How do finings work?

Tags: finings

- What are fining agents?
- How do fining agents work?

Comment: Can't believe this question hasn't be asked yet, lol

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Original Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finings)

The What

> Finings are substances that are usually added at or near the
>   completion of the processing of brewing wine, beer, and various
>   nonalcoholic juice beverages. Their purpose is for removal of organic
>   compounds; to either improve clarity or adjust flavor/aroma.
>   Specifically, the removed compounds may be sulfides, proteins,
>   polyphenols, benzenoids, or copper ions. Unless they form a stable
>   bottom sediment in the final container, the spent finings are usually
>   discarded from the beverage along with the target compounds that they
>   capture.

The How: Neutralising Charges

> The electrostatic types comprise the vast majority. Their purpose is
>   to selectively remove proteins, tannins (polyphenolics) and coloring
>   particles (melanoidins). They must be used as a batch technique, as
>   opposed to flow-through processing methods such as filters. Their
>   particles each have an electric charge which is attracted to the
>   oppositely charged particles of the colloidal dispersion that they are
>   breaking. The result is that the two substances become bound as a
>   stable complex; their net charge becoming neutral. Thus the
>   agglomeration of a semi-solid follows, which may be separated from the
>   beverage either as a floating or settled mass.

The How: Absorbtion

> Although activated carbon may be implemented as a flow-through filter, it is also commonly
>   utilized as a batch ingredient, which later must be separated and
>   discarded from the beverage. It can completely/partially remove
>   benzenoid compounds and all classes of polyphenols non-specifically,
>   decolorizing and deodorizing juices and wines.

The How: Enzymes

> The enzymatic finings are pectin and pectinase. They aid in destroying
>   the large polysaccharide molecule named pectin,[clarification needed]
>   which otherwise causes haze in fruit wines and juices. They are among
>   the few finings that are added before juices are fermented.