# Sediment in bottled elderflower wine

Tags: troubleshooting

Hi Last year for the first time ever, I made Elderflower wine in September for our daughters wedding March 2014. I've left it alone since bottling it, however I've noticed there is sediment at the bottom of each bottle
[10] what do I do about it?

We opened one and the fizz was brilliant it was like champagne popping, so I don't want to disturb and lose the fizz is there anything I can do so it won't offend the wedding guests

Thanks
Pat

Answer (score 1):

I made the exact same stuff last summer. That stuff is LETHAL! lol I got terribly drunk.

What you have made is referred to as Country Champagne or Country Sparkling Wine, the sediment is Yeast which made the fizz and alcohol.

You have three options in my opinion

1. [Cold Crashing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/what-is-cold-crashing) your bottles and store upright and undisturbed till March. Transfer them gently to wedding do not shake. Explain to everyone "This rustic beauty was made for the special occasion and some sediment may stir up". Polite guest will love it, rude guests can go home.
2. Continually pour the bottles into glasses and do not raise the bottle upright, the swirling will stir up sediment. Pour into glasses and hand out the glasses on trays to guests, so people don't see the sediment.
3. **[Disgorging](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pH9CF756ZM)** This is the process of storing bottles upsidedown and rotating over weeks for sediment to rest in the lid. When very cold a quick upside down pop of the lid shots out the sediment. You must place your thumb over the opening immediately! to not lose everything! When pressure calms down remove your thumb and top up with more champagne from a donor bottle (wine+sugar) and re-seal the bottles, the fizz will be regained.

   To Aid you, you can have the bottles upside down in ice and salt to freeze **only** the neck, so that slush sediment is forced out a little slower so you loose less wine.

I've got three bottles for disgorging just for giggles! I recommend practicing on sugar water and yeast first and watching tutorials if you really really wanna go down that route.

My advice is 1 and 2.